# php regexp recurring couldn't figure out

Tags: php, regex, recursion

Hi I'm having some problems with php recurring regexp. I have strings like
`{{if(x=y)? {{ true do something || false do something else }}`
in my html files. It will be some kind of basic template engine. If I use

```
$matches=array();
$content = "{{if(x=y)? true do something || false do something else }}";
preg_match_all('/\{\{if\((.*?)\)\?(.*?)\|\|(.*?)\}\}/is',$content,$matches);
```

returns the results as I expected.

```
Array(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => {{if(x=y)?
            true do something 
               ||
            false do something else 
               }}
    )
 [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => x=y
    )
 [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => true do something 
    )
 [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => false do something else 
    )
)
```

But if the pattern is nested with another one like;

```
{{if(x=y)?
  {{if(y=z)?
     true do something 
   || 
     false do something else 
  }}
||
  {{if(x=a)?
    true do something 
  || 
   false do something else 
  }}
}}
```

it takes the first "}}" chars as end of pattern and fails

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => {{if(x=y)?
            {{if(y=z)?
          true do something 
            ||
          false do something else 
            }}
        )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => x=y
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => {{if(y=z)?
    true do something   
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    false do something else     
    )
)
```

I would like to make a recurring regexp so in each part of true or false it should check if the matched content has same pattern again. The logical part of If is already done. I just need a regexp will match the parts so I can loop thru the results.With my Regexp knowledge this is all I could do so far.**EDIT**
to be more descriptive I need a regexp can parse something like this.

```
{{if()?{{if()?{{if()?...||...}}||{{if()?...||...}}}}||{{if()?{{if()?...||...}}||{{if()?...||...}}}}}}
```

but the regexp I used can only catches from first {{if to first }} it finds which returns

```
{{if(){{if(){{if()...||...}}
```

which is correct for the regexp. But how can I rule the regexp as "get whole text, find the block between {{if()? and }} till the end and ignore any others if it is not at the end" or "get the most outer {{if()?||}} block.
Thanks

Comment: Your syntax isn't quite obvious. Are the brace pairs supposed to be balanced? (they're not in either case).

Comment: I edited it the way it is on page. sorry. It is like basic if clause for php, but instead of using php code in html template I'm trying to make it easier for my client. so when they put an if clause like this in their content, the template class I made should parse it and replace it with the values predefined. like `{{if(pagetitle)?{{ print pagetitle || {{if(company_name)? print company_name|| print ''}} }}`

Comment: Why not just use a real templating system? May I recommend [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: Okay, simply put, it's not possible. In your last example you cannot possibly get all three `if` blocks. You cannot get them in 3 different matches because **matches cannot overlap**. You also cannot get them in 3 different captures of the same match, because for every capture group (i.e. every set of parentheses) in your pattern, there will always be exactly one capture. If the group is reused (through recursion) you will only the the inner- or outermost block. All you can do with regex is verify correct syntax. Parsing will have to be done separately (of a recursive `preg_replace_callback`).

Comment: @Mathletics We don't want to use a template system because we don't have enough time and sources to learn and implement into our system. Also template systems like smarty is so complicated to offer our clients to explain them how to edit their pages. That's why we want to create our own basic template engine to use very very simple codes and less work.

Comment: @m.buettner Thank you for your detailed explanation. My goal here is not to match all nested ones recursively but at least get the parts from the most outer and pass them to same function to match same structure again.But the problem here is when I parse it with this regexp it catches the first }} as closing tag and ignores the rest. As in my example regexp and text the matches[0] is `{{if(x=y)?
  {{if(y=z)? true do something || false do something else}}`
which at least it should be the whole text from `{{if(...) ... || ...}}` then I can send the matches[2] and matches[3] to the same function

Comment: @GuyFawkes: "we don't have enough time and sources to learn and implement into our system."  I suggest that you if you have the time and resources to write, debug and maintain your own homegrown templating system, including having to rely on the people of StackOverflow to debug basic functionality of it for you, then you probably also could funnel that time and resources into using an existing, well-written, already-debugged templating system.

Comment: Per your example, in smarty you could just write `{$pageTitle}` instead of forcing your (I assume) non-technical users to write existence checks against all their variables. Are you so sure your system is easier to use than Smarty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with using [link](http://www.greaterscope.net/projects/Vemplator). Author of the script made it simple enough with a different style. In my sample I was trying to match the code blocks with regexp and replace them with the data, but he actually replaced the code blocks into php codes and recreates the files in a different folder with same structure and each time page requested, first checks the file existence and updated time and runs the script. pretty smart. Maybe not a perfect solution and rational but solves my problem. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Nested patterns are not possible with any kind of regular expressions. It's a fundamental restriction in regexps. You need a more powerful form of parser, such as a lexer.

Shortly put, you'd have to iterate manually through every char of your input, parse possible keywords and keep a memory of how many blocks are open.

You are probably much better off by adjusting an existing template system to your needs.